# Finding the measured average angular velocities

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, average

Supposed I have a couple rows of data with recorded measured ratios $\omega_f/\omega_i$ and they ask me for the "Average Measured $\omega_f/\omega_i$ " This may seem like a really trivial solution but wouldn't I just add up all of my data for the measured ratio $\omega_f/\omega_i$  columns and then divide by the number of rows I have? This is for a Physics class by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities here. Which one is correct depends on the context:

1. Add up the ratios as you've said, then divide by the count of numbers you've added together (from your statement, it sounds like you have more than 1 data item per row - you need to count data items summed, not rows).
2. You add up all the $\omega_f$ and add up all the $\omega_i$ and divide the two sums. This is sometimes called a "weighted average".

Without knowing more about the problem, I can't say which is appropriate here. Since you call these angular velocities, I suspect #1, but then I also don't know why you are taking ratios of of angular velocities.